# How to make initializer lists robust to code changes?

Tags: c++

There is this code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Range {
    //bool enabled = false;
    //int index = 0;
    int begin = 0;
    int end = 0;
};

int main()
{
    Range r = { 2, 3 };
    std::cout << r.begin << " " << r.end;
}
```

If I change the contents of the Range structure by uncommenting one of the commented lines, the program compiles, but does not work correctly. If I add a bool type field to the beginning of Range, the compiler at least issues a warning. But if I add a field of type int to the beginning of Range, then there is not even be any warnings.

Is there any way to make sure that when the contents of a structure changes, all initializer lists that initialize it become invalid or at least issue a warning during compilation? Or maybe is there some other reliable way to find all initializer lists of this structure in the code?

In general, I need some reliable way to find all initializers and make sure that the structure is correctly initialized after changes.

Comment: Give `Range` a user-defined constructor taking 4 parameters. Then brace-init lists with fewer than 4 elements should fail to compile.

Comment: Don't spam C++ version tags. Your question has nothing to do with any version.

Comment: I believe compilers have warnings for "not enough initializers".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a constructor when you make the change.

If your use of the type is bound to your code base, you can even remove the constructor after auditing all uses if it is pointless.

This allows you to make it an error to not pass 3 arguments to the initializer list.  The locations of all of the resulting errors tells you where you need to audit the code.

In general, changing the layout of an aggregate is a API change.  API changes need their use to be audited or rewritten.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way to make sure that when the contents of a structure changes, all initializer lists that initialize it become invalid or at least issue a warning during compilation?

You can add a **parameterized ctor** with exactly the number of parameters you want the initializer list to work:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Range {
    bool enabled = false;
    int index = 0;
    int begin = 0;
    int end = 0;
    //parameterized ctor
    Range(bool penabled, int pindex, int pbegin, int pend)
    : enabled(penabled), index(pindex), begin(pbegin), end(pend)
    {
         
    }
};

int main()
{
    //Range r = { 2, 3 };//won't work now 
    Range r = {true,3,4,5};  //works 
    std::cout << r.begin << " " << r.end;
}
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jTv5zKdn6)

Answer (score 1):

That always was a problem with value intialization for constructor vs. aggregate structure. C++20 had introduced following syntax

```
Range  a{.begin = 2, .end = 1};
```

Before that  only defense is a constructor, provided that you already have default values, it doesn't mean much.

Otherwise it does matter *how changes are introduced* into code instead of *how code was written*. A trick I used when dealing with huge and chaotic code base:

1. Add rule-5 functions, constructor should be `explicit`
2. Compile code, fix errors ( and this will find nearly every use of incomplete initializer)
3. Run static analyzer
4. Change both structure and constructor
5. Compile code, fix errors
6. Run through static analyzer
7. Test
8. Remove special functions.

A nasty, long and tedious process. Sometimes I was omitting step 8. Sometimes problems appeared no "test" stage, because original code was getting away with "natural" UBs (e.g. an uninitialized structure had been zero-initialized if it had no constructor).